# Como Poner Puntos suspensivos en un texto con JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Tengo una tabla la cual me trae desde la base de datos una descripción la cual varia la cantidad de caracteres, el problema es que si una descripción tiene "1000" caracteres se muestran en la tabla y eso se ve mal entonces busco la forma de poder acortar esos textos para que no se vea mal visualmente...

Pdta: He visto que con css se puede hacer pero no me interesa hacerlo de esa forma ya que estoy usando datatables....

gracias

Comment: Puedes añadir el código que llevas hasta ahora para poder ayudarte mejor

Comment: no pude añadir codigo porque no tengo el suficiente conocimiento en esa parte. igualmente gracias.

Comment: Si no hay código de tu parte ¿Cómo podemos ayudarte? Si tienes código y no puedes editar tu pregunta, pega el código en los comentarios y te ayudamos a editar la pregunta. Por otro lado, en este mundo de la programación y tecnología tienes mayores oportunidades si te expandes, si sabes hacer X cosa de diferentes maneras a crecer se ha dicho! Tu falta de interés te puede costar caro, te lo digo en buen plan: al estar cerrado a soluciones, inclusive a soluciones alternativas (por más que sientas que son ajenas), tu crecimiento profesional avanzaría a un ritmo muy lento. Espero lo tomes a bien :D

Comment: No lo tomo a mal, es un buen aporte, pero es importante leer bien la duda del usuario para hacer una critica, si bien para algo  este sitio es para obtener un ayuda donde posiblemente ya no hay otra alternativa. Saludos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
function cortarTextoConPuntos(texto, limite)
{
  var puntosSuspensivos = "...";
  if(texto.length > limite)
  {
    texto = texto.substring(0,limite) + puntosSuspensivos;
  }

    return texto;
}

console.log(cortarTextoConPuntos("hola amigos",9));
```

Comment: Gracias tu respuesta me ha funcionado. la probe de distintas formas y funciono.

Answer (score 3):

Te dejo una función genérica.. La llamas con el id del div que quieres formatear, junto con la cantidad de caracteres.

```
function ellipsisJS ( containerId , largomaximo) {
var $container = $("#" + containerId); 
var $text = $("#descripcion p");    

while ( $container.text().length > largomaximo ) {
    $text.text(function (index, text) {
        return text.replace(/\W*\s(\S)*$/, '...');
    });
}
}
```

Y la invocas así

```
ellipsisJS("descripcion", 100);
```

Un ejemplo de como funciona..
https://jsfiddle.net/ng9bdhhz/

Los créditos para http://notasjs.blogspot.cl/2013/05/simular-text-overflowellipsis-para.html

Comment: Gracias tu respuesta funciona me ha funcionado.